# Would it be possible to forward MS Unit tests from an EXE to a DLL?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, dll, mfc

I have an application where there is a mess of code that has a bunch of non-isolated components.  This makes things difficult in terms of doing some unit testing.  So along with some unit tests in their own separate test DLL, I'm trying to also create some tests within the application DLL.  The application DLL is normally invoked from an application EXE.

For some background, this code is 20+ years old written in native C++. I cannot execute the tests in the DLL directly as the framework is not setup, so any calls executed within the DLL will not execute correctly.  I've unsuccessfully tried to do this already, but maybe I need a more fundamental understanding of the MFC framework to do this.

A colleague suggested that *maybe* it might be possible to have the `vstest.console` somehow run the tests through the EXE where the framework can be brought up, run the tests through the EXE, which are then forwarded to the DLL, and then have the test results returned back through the EXE to `vstest.console`, effectively making the EXE a proxy of sorts.

I'm thinking that this might be a longshot, but I'm at a loss as how I can run the tests in the DLL properly.  Could it be done?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

For legacy EXE, you may use Generic Test (for console app) or Coded UI Test (for GUI app). Technically, Generic Test or Coded UI Test is System Level Test. You can still get Code Coverage for the two tests.

### More on Generic Test

**Use a generic test to wrap a console app or test harness console that**

• Runs from a command line

• Returns error code: 0 <- Pass; Nonzero <- Fail

• Positive tests only for a console app; A test harness may include negative tests within.

**Visual Studio treats generic test just like other tests, but**

• Add Generic Tests into Unit Test Project type

• Command line must run .GenericTest file instead of UnitTest1.dll

• vstest.console GenericTest1.GenericTest

**NOTE: Set the “run duration” long enough for your EXE.**

Comment: Cool. I'll have to look into this further. This will state what tests in the DLL succeeded or failed? Not sure what you mean by ` A test harness may include negative tests within.`

Comment: Hmmmm, no, this won't work.  The application is not a console app, so part of the framework to be launched is GUI based.  I don't think that `Generic Test` would work because of that. As for `Coded UI Test`, it requires `Visual Studio Ultimate` or `Visual Studio Premium` which I don't have access to.